# "Intersection" of lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Say I have a list

```
List1={
      {1, *, *, *}, {*, 1, *, *}, {*, *, 1, *}, {*, *, *, 1}, 
      {0, *, *, *}, {*, 0, *, *}, {*, *, 0, *}, {*, *, *, 0} 
      }
```

Let intersection function **meet(a,b)** is the function of two variables  $a$ and $b$ from the list **List1**$\times$**List1** (the elements of **List1** themselves are lists of equal length); 
The function should do the following:

**IF** there is no $i$ with ($a_i=1$ and $b_i=0$) OR ($a_i=0$ and $b_i=1$)

> then **meet(-,-)** adds as an element (by Union[-,-])to the **List1**
>   the list $m$ of the same length as $a$ and $b$, 
>   such that for each $i$
>
> > **If** ($a_i=1$ and $b_i=*$) OR ($a_i=*$ and $b_i=1$) OR ($a_i=1$ and $b_i=1$) then $m_i=1$,
> >
> > **else if** ($a_i=0$ and $b_i=*$) OR ($a_i=*$ and $b_i=0$) OR ($a_i=0$ and $b_i=0$) then $m_i=0$,
> >
> > **else** (if we have $a_i=*$ and $b_i=*$) $m_i=*$

**ELSE** (i.e. if there is $i$ with $a_i=1$ and $b_i=0$ OR $a_i=0$ and $b_i=1$)

> adds nothing to the **List1** (does nothing).

I want to iterate **meet(-,-)** on the **List1** to add all such intersections until the operation terminates.

In particular the intersection of two elements of **List1**

```
{1, *, *, *}
```

and

```
{*, 1, *, *}
```

is as described above a list (an element)

```
{1, 1, *, *}
```

since this element is not yet in **List1**, then **meet({1, *, *, *},{*, 1, *, *})** adds this element  to the **List1**

while

```
{1, *, *, 0}
```

and

```
{*, 1, *, 1}
```

have no intersecton (since on 4th place we have 0 and 1 respectively) and hence the function adds nothing to the **List1**

Finally I want to have **List1** equal to

```
{
 {1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, *}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, *}, 
 {1, 1, *, 1}, {1, 1, *, 0}, {1, 1, *, *}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, *}, 
 {1, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, *}, {1, 0, *, 1}, {1, 0, *, 0}, {1, 0, *, *}, 
 {1, *, 1, 1}, {1, *, 1, 0}, {1, *, 1, *}, {1, *, 0, 1}, {1, *, 0, 0}, {1, *, 0, *}, 
 {1, *, *, 1}, {1, *, *, 0}, {1, *, *, *}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1, 1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, *}, 
 {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, *}, {0, 1, *, 1}, {0, 1, *, 0}, {0, 1, *, *}, 
 {0, 0, 1, 1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, *}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, *}, 
 {0, 0, *, 1}, {0, 0, *, 0}, {0, 0, *, *}, {0, *, 1, 1}, {0, *, 1, 0}, {0, *, 1, *}, 
 {0, *, 0, 1}, {0, *, 0, 0}, {0, *, 0, *}, {0, *, *, 1}, {0, *, *, 0}, {0, *, *, *}, 
 {*, 1, 1, 1}, {*, 1, 1, 0}, {*, 1, 1, *}, {*, 1, 0, 1}, {*, 1, 0, 0}, {*, 1, 0, *}, 
 {*, 1, *, 1}, {*, 1, *, 0}, {*, 1, *, *}, {*, 0, 1, 1}, {*, 0, 1, 0}, {*, 0, 1, *}, 
 {*, 0, 0, 1}, {*, 0, 0, 0}, {*, 0, 0, *}, {*, 0, *, 1}, {*, 0, *, 0}, {*, 0, *, *}, 
 {*, *, 1, 1}, {*, *, 1, 0}, {*, *, 1, *}, {*, *, 0, 1}, {*, *, 0, 0}, {*, *, 0, *}, 
 {*, *, *, 1}, {*, *, *, 0}
}
```

> What is a efficient way to do such expansion of an initial list List1 effectively  in Wolfram Mathematica?

Comment: I must admit, I've reread this a few times and I'm not 100% sure what the operation we're trying to achieve here is.

Comment: Ok I'll try to clarify the question.

Comment: what is the desired  result for `List2={{1, "*", "*"}, {"*", 1, "*"}, {"*", "*", 0}}`?

Comment: I made changes, if someone helps me to write down the desired code I will be appreciate, I realize what to do but do not know how to do it in a proper way.

Comment: What is the intersection of `{1, *, *, 1}` and `{*, 1, *, 0}`?

Comment: They have no intersection since at forth place first has 1 and second has 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ClearAll[f, g, h]
f["*", a_] := a
f[a_, "*"] := a
f[a_, a_] := a
f[a_, b_] /; a != b := "*"

SetAttributes[f, Listable]
g = DeleteCases[DeleteDuplicates[f @@@ Tuples[#, {2}]], {"*" ..}] &;

h = FixedPoint[g, #]&
```

(You can also use `Nest[h, #, 2]&`.)

**Example:**

Input list from OP:

```
List1 = {{1, "*", "*", "*"}, {"*", 1, "*", "*"}, {"*", "*", 1, 
    "*"}, {"*", "*", "*", 1}, {0, "*", "*", "*"}, {"*", 0, "*", 
    "*"}, {"*", "*", 0, "*"}, {"*", "*", "*", 0}};
```

Desired output from OP:

```
List2 = {{1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, 0}, {1, 1, 1, "*"}, {1, 1, 0, 1}, {1,
    1, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, "*"}, {1, 1, "*", 1}, {1, 1, "*", 0}, {1, 1, 
   "*", "*"}, {1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0}, {1, 0, 1, "*"}, {1, 0, 0, 
   1}, {1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0, "*"}, {1, 0, "*", 1}, {1, 0, "*", 
   0}, {1, 0, "*", "*"}, {1, "*", 1, 1}, {1, "*", 1, 0}, {1, "*", 1, 
   "*"}, {1, "*", 0, 1}, {1, "*", 0, 0}, {1, "*", 0, "*"}, {1, "*", 
   "*", 1}, {1, "*", "*", 0}, {1, "*", "*", "*"}, {0, 1, 1, 1}, {0, 1,
    1, 0}, {0, 1, 1, "*"}, {0, 1, 0, 1}, {0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 
   "*"}, {0, 1, "*", 1}, {0, 1, "*", 0}, {0, 1, "*", "*"}, {0, 0, 1, 
   1}, {0, 0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1, "*"}, {0, 0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
   0, 0, "*"}, {0, 0, "*", 1}, {0, 0, "*", 0}, {0, 0, "*", "*"}, {0, 
   "*", 1, 1}, {0, "*", 1, 0}, {0, "*", 1, "*"}, {0, "*", 0, 1}, {0, 
   "*", 0, 0}, {0, "*", 0, "*"}, {0, "*", "*", 1}, {0, "*", "*", 
   0}, {0, "*", "*", "*"}, {"*", 1, 1, 1}, {"*", 1, 1, 0}, {"*", 1, 1,
    "*"}, {"*", 1, 0, 1}, {"*", 1, 0, 0}, {"*", 1, 0, "*"}, {"*", 1, 
   "*", 1}, {"*", 1, "*", 0}, {"*", 1, "*", "*"}, {"*", 0, 1, 
   1}, {"*", 0, 1, 0}, {"*", 0, 1, "*"}, {"*", 0, 0, 1}, {"*", 0, 0, 
   0}, {"*", 0, 0, "*"}, {"*", 0, "*", 1}, {"*", 0, "*", 0}, {"*", 0, 
   "*", "*"}, {"*", "*", 1, 1}, {"*", "*", 1, 0}, {"*", "*", 1, 
   "*"}, {"*", "*", 0, 1}, {"*", "*", 0, 0}, {"*", "*", 0, "*"}, {"*",
    "*", "*", 1}, {"*", "*", "*", 0}};
```

`h @ List1` and `List2` are same up to sorting:

```
Sort @ h @ List1 == Sort @ List2
```

> True

Comment: Works perfect, the bad thing I am do not understand what is what inside it yet :D

Comment: What I notice just now is that $h$ does not give all elements when length of list is greater then 4. In particular, when an initial list **List1** is the list of all lists with exactly one $1$ inside, then the list of all "intersections" should be of size $\sum_n^kC_n^k-1$ and to have all desired elements I need to call the function $h$ twice. 
Can you change the code in such a way that it iterates itself until all "intersections" are there inside an output list?

Comment: Oh, thanks for edit!!!